# OrmLite Row Mapping issue

Tags: android, ormlite

I have two classes

```
public class UserDto {
          private long id;
          private Coordinate coordinate;
     }
  public class Coordinate {
          private double lat;
          private double lng;
     }
```

Using OrmLite I want to store `User` in database as

```
public class User {
              private long id;
              private double lat;
              private double lng;
         }
```

But after query I want to get as `UserDto`

I don't want to use something like

```
List<User> users = userDao.queryForAll();
    List<UserDto> dtos = new ArrayList<UserDto>();
    for(User user : users){
        UserDto dto = new UserDto(user);
        dtos.add(dto);
    }
```

I want to OrmLite do it automaticaly for every query.
I guess it can be achieved via RowMapper, but don't know how.
Is it possible?